How to move record from table A to B and update picked status in table A for the inserted records
I need to move records from table A to table B in Spring Boot + Oracle DB. Only a subset of columns from each record in A are moved to B.
For example, from A(a_id, user_id, name, email, phone, status, picked_state), I need to insert into B(b_id, user_id, name, status) where a_id, b_id are auto generated IDs for the corresponding tables.
I don't prefer to use any CDC for this!
Furthermore, I am trying to implement the logic in Spring Boot app itself without using PL/SQL.
Currently, I am running a method every 10 seconds to check for records in table A with picked_state as null. Take and insert that records to table B.
Then I am setting the column 'picked_state' to PICKED in table A after I insert a record to B like:
UPDATE table_a SET picked_state = 'PICKED', processed_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE txn_ref_no IN (SELECT transaction_id FROM table_b);

Here, I am checking for the record was inserted to table B.
Every operations I mentioned like insert, update, select etc are done by executing native sql query itself from the application. Currently, I am running these queries with EntityManager createNativeQuery()
But in this query,
SELECT transaction_id FROM table_b

will be large as records are being inserted into table_b continuously. This does not seem to be an efficient approach. What are the possible ways to efficiently handle this?

Is there a reason why you haven't considered using a trigger on table A? That would probably be the easiest solution. Any time there's an insert or an update on table A, you could trigger an insert into table B

@Boneist, problem isn't in moving rows from here to there, but in updating source table.

@Boneist Yes. There are some extra logic, processing done on the data before sending from A to B. I have kept the problem statement simple in order to focus on the main issue.

So the process is: insert unprocessed rows into table A, process the rows - during which, rows are inserted into table B - and then update the status column(s) for the rows in table A you know have been processed (because a row has been inserted into table B)? If so, maybe the trigger should be on table B - i.e. when a row is inserted into table B, find the corresponding row in table A and update the status column(s).

Did you try EXISTS? Might perform better than IN.
UPDATE table_a a SET 
  picked_state = 'PICKED', 
  processed_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
              FROM table_b b
              WHERE b.transaction_id = a.txn_ref_no
             );


Another option might be to first fetch the last ID, and then update only rows that were recently added. That requires PL/SQL, though.
DECLARE
   l_max_id  NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT MAX (b.b_id)
     INTO l_max_id
     FROM table_b b;

   INSERT INTO table_b (user_id, name, status)
      SELECT user_id, name, status
        FROM table_a a
       WHERE a.picked_state <> 'PICKED';

   UPDATE table_a a
      SET a.picked_state = 'PICKED', a.processed_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    WHERE EXISTS
             (SELECT NULL
                FROM table_b b
               WHERE     b.transaction_id = a.txn_ref_no
                     AND b.b_id > l_max_id);
END;


I was trying to implement the logic in Spring Boot app itself without using PL/SQL. I have  updated the question accordingly.

I don't know Spring Boot so - if you can't use PL/SQL - you'll have to find another way. Good luck!

PL/SQL is considered as a backup plan if there isn't any other way to solve this.

You could use MERGE INTO like here:
-- Insert into table B with data from table A 
MERGE INTO B b 
USING ( Select      *
        From        A
      ) a ON( a.A_ID = b.B_ID )  -- and/or any other actual join condition
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN    -- if there is no matching row in table B it will be inserted
     INSERT (b.B_ID, b.USER_ID, b.NAME, b.STATUS) 
     VALUES (a.A_ID, a.USER_ID, a.NAME, a.STATUS)

-- Update table A with data from table B
MERGE INTO A a 
USING ( Select      *
        From        B
      ) b ON( b.B_ID = a.A_ID And       -- and/or any other actual join condition
              EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM B Where TRANSACTION_ID = a.TXN_REF_NO )
            )
WHEN MATCHED THEN    -- if there exist matching row(s) update columns
     UPDATE SET a.PICKED_STATE = 'PICKED', 
                a.PROCESSED_AT = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE a.PICKED_STATE Is Null


Do it all in a single PL/SQL statement:
DECLARE
  TYPE rowid_table IS TABLE OF ROWID;
  v_rowids rowid_table;
BEGIN
  UPDATE a
  SET    picked_state = 'picked',
         processed_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  WHERE  picked_state IS NULL
  RETURNING rowid BULK COLLECT INTO v_rowids;

  FORALL i IN 1 .. v_rowids.COUNT
    INSERT INTO b (user_id, name, status)
    SELECT user_id, name, status
    FROM   a
    WHERE  ROWID = v_rowids(i);
END;

or
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO b (user_id, name, status)
  SELECT user_id, name, status
  FROM   a
  WHERE  picked_state IS NULL;

  UPDATE a
  SET    picked_state = 'picked',
         processed_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  WHERE  picked_state IS NULL;
END;

or:
DECLARE
  TYPE rowid_table IS TABLE OF ROWID;
  v_rowids rowid_table;
BEGIN
  SELECT ROWID
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_rowids
  FROM   a
  WHERE  picked_state IS NULL
  FOR UPDATE;

  FORALL i IN 1 .. v_rowids.COUNT
    INSERT INTO b (user_id, name, status)
    SELECT user_id, name, status
    FROM   a
    WHERE  ROWID = v_rowids(i);

  FORALL i IN 1 .. v_rowids.COUNT
    UPDATE a
    SET    picked_state = 'picked',
           processed_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    WHERE  ROWID = v_rowids(i);
END;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE a (
  a_id    NUMBER(10,0)
          GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
          PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id NUMBER(10,0),
  name    VARCHAR2(50),
  status  VARCHAR2(10),
  processed_at DATE,
  picked_state VARCHAR2(10)
);

CREATE TABLE b (
  b_id    NUMBER(10,0)
          GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
          PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id NUMBER(10,0),
  name    VARCHAR2(50),
  status  VARCHAR2(10)
);

INSERT INTO a (user_id, name, status, processed_at, picked_state)
  SELECT 1, 'Alice', 'status', DATE '1970-01-01', 'picked' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Alice', 'status', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Betty', 'status', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Carol', 'status', DATE '1970-01-01', 'picked' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'Carol', 'status', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL;

Then, after the UPDATE and INSERT, the tables contain:



A_ID
USER_ID
NAME
STATUS
PROCESSED_AT
PICKED_STATE




1
1
Alice
status
1970-01-01 00:00:00
picked


2
1
Alice
status
2024-05-21 10:55:10
picked


3
2
Betty
status
2024-05-21 10:55:10
picked


4
3
Carol
status
1970-01-01 00:00:00
picked


5
4
Carol
status
2024-05-21 10:55:10
picked






B_ID
USER_ID
NAME
STATUS




1
1
Alice
status


2
2
Betty
status


3
4
Carol
status



fiddle

I am trying to implement the logic in Spring Boot app itself without using PL/SQL. I have updated the question accordingly. I apologize for the lack of clarity in my initial question.

@PaulsBaby You can run PL/SQL using createNativeQuery() which appears to be what you are already doing since you state "Currently, I am running these queries with EntityManager createNativeQuery()" so I'm confused why PL/SQL is not an option?

In fact, there is some processing done before sending record to table B. I want to keep the processing logic in application itself.

@PaulsBaby You can keep the logic in the application and run it before calling the database and can put the PL/SQL statement into the application and call it using em.createNativeQuery("<the PL/SQL statement>") so that all the code will be in one place. I'm still not seeing what precludes the use of PL/SQL (or why running one UPDATE and one INSERT statement in separate commands is valid but a single PL/SQL block containing both is not). You probably need to include a [MRE] with more details of the Spring-Boot code in your question.

I was looking for some method like, to get the user_id from record inserted to B and then update the picked_state in record for that particular user_id in table A. Is this possible with Oracle? Or something even better! FYI using PL/SQL to combine the insert, update operations is in mind as a backup plan.

@PaulsBaby "Is this possible with Oracle?" Yes, typically you would use PL/SQL for this. You could SELECT all the a_id and return them to Java and then go back to the database and do the INSERTs and then go back to Java and then do the UPDATEs but that is inefficient to keep returning control back to Java when you can, instead, hand it off to the database in a single PL/SQL block to do it all.
